# Avoid undefined properties when concatentating strings

Tags: javascript

JavaScript returns the string 'undefined' when you concatenate undefined to a string. Normally this is an issue when the string to be concatenated is undefined, but in my example obj.prop can be undefined at any time. I'd like to avoid this pattern in my code in cases like this

```
function (obj) {
  if (obj.prop) {
    obj.prop += 'string';
  } else {
    obj.prop = 'string';
  }
}
```

If I always do '+= string' I end up with 'undefinedstring' in the case obj.prop was undefined

Comment: `if (obj.prop && obj.prop !== 'undefined') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `undefined` is considered falsey, you could implement it this way:

```
function (obj) {
  obj.prop = obj.prop || '';
  obj.prop += 'string';
}
```

or in a similar way:

```
function (obj) {
  obj.prop = (obj.prop || '') + 'string';
}
```

Comment: Since `undefined` is considered as `falsey` -- which is very different from a  `0`.  `0` just happens to be falsey as well.

Comment: correct. i will edit that. when i wrote 0 i was using the "non zero" terminology

Comment: You could make that a little more generic `function appendStr(obj, prop, str)`

Comment: that is also correct, although thats not the original question. you could make it even more generic with `Object.prototype.appendStr = function(prop, str)`

Comment: Wow I was not expecting such an response over this. Thanks!

Comment: Accepting this answer as it contains the solution, however the issue is the += operator. The only pattern that works is the first example you posted. Doing it inline in an expression causes the unwanted behavior.

Comment: thats strange. do you have a fiddle which the second example dose not work?

Comment: You're misunderstanding my question. I would like to do '+=' all the time without having to check for undefined properties. I don't think there's an simple solution outside a helper function on the proto.

Comment: I understand. using `a+=b` is just like using `a=a+b`, and therfore, if you want to prevent falsey values of concating you could write `a=(a||'')+b`. thats the solution and it dose just the same as `+=`, except it replaces null/undefined with `''`

Comment: Ah my mistake. It would have been helpful if you explained that in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this style of code,

```
function (obj) {  
    obj.prop += ( !!obj.prop ? obj.prop : "" );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasOwnProperty`, it returns `true` if the object has propery else returns false;

```
function (obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
    obj.prop += 'string';
  else 
    obj.prop = 'string';
}
```

Comment: The object can have that property and it can still be undefined. The OP wants to avoid this if/else

Comment: @JuanMendes, it can not be undefined, it can be null though.

Comment: @JuanMendes where did the OP say thay wanted to avoid `if/else`? They just want it to return `string` instead of `undefinedstring`

Comment: It can be undefined: `obj.prop = undefined`. Also, see `"If I always do '+= string' I end up with 'undefinedstring' in the case obj.prop was undefined"`. The OP can get around the problem with the "if/else". They would like `"to avoid this pattern in my code in cases like this"`